# MongoDb: add element to array if not exists

Tags: mongodb

I'm using node.js and Mongo.db (I'm newly on Mongo). I have a document like this:

```
Tag : {
   name: string,
   videoIDs: array
}
```

The idea is, the server receives a JSON like

```
JSON: { 
    name: "sport",
    videoId: "34f54e34c"
}
```

with this JSON, it has to find the tag with the same name and check if in the array it has the `videoId`, if not, insert it to the array.

How can I check the array and append data?

Comment: `in the array it has the videoId` Which array you are talking about?

Answer (score 178, accepted):

You can use `$addToSet` operator to check exist before append element into array.

```
db.tags.update(
    {name: 'sport'},
    {$addToSet: { videoIDs: "34f54e34c" } }
);
```

In this update statement example, mongoDB will find the TAG document which matches `name == sport`, and then check whether the `videoIDs` array contains `34f54e34c`. If not, append it to the array.

Detail usage of `$addToSet` please read [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/).

Comment: @albert , yes you can insert one element. "videoIDs" is an array, and you want to insert string "34f54e34c" into it if not exists, right?

Comment: It works, it add new ids if there aren't, avoiding duplicates

Comment: What if the field 'videoIDs' doesn't exist to start with?

Comment: @GauravOjha, if the field 'videoIDs' doesn't exist before executing the update statement, it will be created automatically

Comment: can any one tell when $addtoSet got introduced, I mean from which mongodb version.?

Comment: I also want to increment the count if the add to set operation is performed

Comment: @ShantanuMadane, pls refer to `$inc`. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/

Comment: @yellowB I actually want to increment only if $add to set adds element to an array. How can I achieve that? I know I can write two different queries but I want to do it in a single query. Is this possible?

Comment: @ShantanuMadane，yes you can put multiple update operations into single statement，e.g. {$addToSet :  { videoId : "34f54e34c"}, $inc: {count: 1}}

Comment: does `$addToSet` create the array if it's not yet to exist?

Comment: An array is typically expected to have a deterministic order, but $addToSet does not guarantee a particular ordering of elements in the modified set (see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/#behavior)

Comment: I am having some trouble with objects. I saw in the documentation that the object must have the same attributes. Is there a way to use only the _id for addToSet, but adding a full document?

Answer (score 8):

I didn't test it, but you can try something like:

```
yourDb.find({ name: "sport", 
              videoIDs: { $in: ["34f54e34c"] } })
      .update({$addToSet: { videoIDs: "34f54e34c" }});
```

If you need how: MongoDb in nodeJs implementation, you can start with:

http://jsfiddle.net/1ku0z1a1/

Answer (score 7):

`$addToSet` operator check for the empty or existing array in document.

```
 db.col_name.update({name :"name_for_match"},{$addToSet :  { videoId : "video_id_value"}})
```