# how to update nested array in array object in mongodb?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

hi I have next document:

```
var house = {
    "name": name1,
    "steps":[
        {
          "step_id":1,
          "members": [
            {
               "user_id": 7,
             },
             {
               "user_id": 1
            }
          ]
       }
    }
  }
```

I need do next:
find house in DB by name,
  than find step by step_id,
 than to insert Object {'user_id':2} into members in the step, 
if such Object  doesn't exist there. if exists don't do anything.

Tried like this, but it doesn't work:

```
  db.collection('my_collection').update(
     { "name":"name1",  "steps.step_id": 1 },
    { "$set": { "steps.$.members.user_id": 10 } }
```

thank you guys in advance.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38970835/mongodb-add-element-to-array-if-not-exists)

Comment: Your model looks invalid, you're setting the `user_id` property on your member object multiple times.

Comment: sorry will edit now. my bad

Comment: Rob M. worked. thanks.